# Is it possible to abstract SignalR and SignalR Core to be used on one client?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm in a situation where I have a WinForms client that connects to a WebApi and this WebApi has SignalR. Now, an ASP.Net Core version of the WebApi is being developed, and it's using SignalR Core. At this stage of development, the client can't move directly to use solely SignalR Core so it needs to support both versions.

The only couple of hub proxy methods that are used throughout are `On<T>` and `Invoke`.

So the idea was to create an abstraction layer, so I created such a class:

```
public class ClassicService : IHubService
{
    private HubConnection hubConnection;
    private Dictionary<HubType, IHubProxy> hubs;

    public IHubService Build(string token)
    {
        hubConnection = new HubConnection("serverurl");

        hubs = new Dictionary<HubType, IHubProxy>() {
            { HubType.Notification, hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("NotificationHub")             
        };

        return this;
    }

    public IHubService Start()
    {
        hubConnection.Start().Wait();
        return this;
    }

    public IHub GetHub(HubType hubType)
    {
        return hubs[hubType];
    }
}
```

And the `IHub` interface looks like this:

```
public interface IHub
{
    Task Invoke(string method, params object[] args);
    IDisposable On(string eventName, Action onData);
    IDisposable On<T>(string eventName, Action<T> onData);
}
```

However, the problem is when trying to get a hub by calling the `GetHub` method because IHubProxy cannot be cast to `IHub`.

Is there a way to build this abstraction layer and get it to work?

Comment: You should never abstract a special framework. Instead abstract what you are really trying to do and one possible implementation will utilize that special framework. As a real world example: Do not abstract a hammer, but define a IPictureMountingService and a possible concrete solution could be to use a hammer

Answer (score 0):

You use "SignalR Core" in ".NET Core" clients and in a ".NET Framework" client you'd use normal "SignalR"... so you wouldn't use both of them in one client at all, it just doesn't make sense, since it depends on the framework of your client.

So a "WinForms" project with ".NET Framework" will always use "SignalR".

Comment: From what I read is that a SignalR client won't work with the SignalR Core server.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono i think you could take a look at: [Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client/)
, but I don't know if it will help you. You have to understand that you can't even use the normal SignalR Core Client implementation in WinForms under .NET Framework, so an simple abstraction won't be enough

Comment: That's the 'Core' version which I also added to the WinForms Client as it supported by 4.6.1. After adding both versions the plan was to abstract their functionality.